# Compiling SOIL with Clion

Tags: c++, compilation, clion, soil

I've tried to use SOIL on one of my projects, but it needs to be compiled first, because it is not a header-only library. Unfortunately, attempting such with Clion only delivers lots of compiler errors, as the project wasn't made with CMake. I've tried compiling versions of SOIL that were "tailored for CMake" like this one: https://github.com/paralin/soil without success.

Simply using the lib file along with the sources that were provided by SOIL without further compilation results in linker errors in my main project similar to these:
[linking soil, mingw, undef ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50068522/linking-soil-mingw-undef-ref)

`undefined reference to 'glGetString@4'`

But the provided solution of including `-lsoil` in the linker options did not work for me.

How do I properly include SOIL in my project or properly compile it, assuming I made no mistakes in including it?